# Google BigQuery SQL: Extract data from JSON (list and array) into columns and rows

Tags: google-bigquery

**Data as in big Query**
[image]

**Output Required**
[image]

**Request everyone to design a query to get desired output in Big Query**

Comment: Look at this and you may find the answer you need - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json-data

Comment: looks same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74221557/how-to-extract-json-json-is-without-quotation-marks-array-stored-as-string-in to me.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments this link may have what you need: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json-data

It's hard to understand what you want with the limited information in the question but the desired output may not be suitable for data since Each ID that you have can be associated with more than one sku.

Also unless you are purely using google sql, you probably just want to get all the data then format the JSON that is returned after that. So if you are using JavaScript you would want to convert the json to an object like so:

```
var object = JSON.parse(data);
```

Then you can take the sku value from the data object you have recieved.

```
var sku = object[0].sku
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below  option

```
select id, sku
from your_table,
unnest(regexp_extract_all(data, r'\bsku:([^},]*)\b')) sku
```

if applied to dummy data similar to what you have in question - output is

[image]